# Refused to create a worker from 'blob:<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "child-src 'self' *.website.com

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, worker, gltf

I am trying to build chrome extension (MV3) - there I am loading some libraries which uses workers - I added the worker (.js and .wasm) in the resource folder so I can load them "locally" into the chrome extension - also added them to the manifest. But I still get this error on some sites:

```
Refused to create a worker from 'blob:<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "child-src 'self' *.website.com cdn.cookielaw.org geolocation.onetrust.com privacyportal-de.onetrust.com *.youtube.com pay.sandbox.datatrans.com pay.datatrans.com siteintercept.qualtrics.com *.siteintercept.qualtrics.com website.com.qualtrics.com". Note that 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'child-src' is used as a fallback.

index.js:42287 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Access to the script at 'blob:https://www.website.com/4e6cdd96-13ca-4eef-9603-f241cf776a61' is denied by the document's Content Security Policy.
    at chrome-extension://nlphfnalpjgilnheibacdlongcbapgdi/assets/js/index.js:42287:25
(anonymous) @ index.js:42287
Promise.then (async)
decodeDracoFile @ index.js:42180
(anonymous) @ index.js:40581
(anonymous) @ index.js:40580
Promise.then (async)
decodePrimitive @ index.js:40579
createDracoPrimitive @ index.js:41564
loadGeometries @ index.js:41578
loadMesh @ index.js:41604
(anonymous) @ index.js:41080
_invokeOne @ index.js:41042
getDependency @ index.js:41079
createNodeMesh @ index.js:41796
(anonymous) @ index.js:41860
_invokeOne @ index.js:41042
_loadNodeShallow @ index.js:41859
loadNode @ index.js:41819
(anonymous) @ index.js:41075
_invokeOne @ index.js:41042
getDependency @ index.js:41074
loadNode @ index.js:41823
(anonymous) @ index.js:41075
_invokeOne @ index.js:41042
getDependency @ index.js:41074
loadScene @ index.js:41939
getDependency @ index.js:41071
(anonymous) @ index.js:41139
getDependencies @ index.js:41138
(anonymous) @ index.js:40954
Promise.then (async)
parse @ index.js:40952
parse @ index.js:39831
(anonymous) @ index.js:39722
(anonymous) @ index.js:24934
Promise.then (async)
load @ index.js:24927
load @ index.js:39720
Avatar @ index.js:42471
Ke @ index.js:32492
Sh @ index.js:35555
Rh @ index.js:35223
Qh @ index.js:35216
Gh @ index.js:35199
Eh @ index.js:34833
J @ index.js:30893
R @ index.js:30923
Show 43 more frames
Show less
2index.js:42287 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Access to the script at 'blob:https://www.website.com/4e6cdd96-13ca-4eef-9603-f241cf776a61' is denied by the document's Content Security Policy.
    at chrome-extension://nlphfnalpjgilnheibacdlongcbapgdi/assets/js/index.js:42287:25
(anonymous) @ index.js:42287
Promise.then (async)
decodeDracoFile @ index.js:42180
(anonymous) @ index.js:40581
(anonymous) @ index.js:40580
Promise.then (async)
decodePrimitive @ index.js:40579
createDracoPrimitive @ index.js:41564
loadGeometries @ index.js:41578
loadMesh @ index.js:41604
(anonymous) @ index.js:41080
_invokeOne @ index.js:41042
getDependency @ index.js:41079
createNodeMesh @ index.js:41796
(anonymous) @ index.js:41860
_invokeOne @ index.js:41042
_loadNodeShallow @ index.js:41859
loadNode @ index.js:41819
(anonymous) @ index.js:41075
_invokeOne @ index.js:41042
getDependency @ index.js:41074
loadScene @ index.js:41939
getDependency @ index.js:41071
(anonymous) @ index.js:41139
getDependencies @ index.js:41138
(anonymous) @ index.js:40954
Promise.then (async)
parse @ index.js:40952
parse @ index.js:39831
(anonymous) @ index.js:39722
(anonymous) @ index.js:24934
Promise.then (async)
load @ index.js:24927
load @ index.js:39720
Avatar @ index.js:42471
Ke @ index.js:32492
Sh @ index.js:35555
Rh @ index.js:35223
Qh @ index.js:35216
Gh @ index.js:35199
Eh @ index.js:34833
J @ index.js:30893
R @ index.js:30923
Show 39 more frames
Show less
index.js:42287 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Access to the script at 'blob:https://www.website.com/bba676dc-3fea-4b55-badb-51addf2963a3' is denied by the document's Content Security Policy.
    at chrome-extension://nlphfnalpjgilnheibacdlongcbapgdi/assets/js/index.js:42287:25
(anonymous) @ index.js:42287
Promise.then (async)
decodeDracoFile @ index.js:42180
(anonymous) @ index.js:40581
(anonymous) @ index.js:40580
Promise.then (async)
decodePrimitive @ index.js:40579
createDracoPrimitive @ index.js:41564
loadGeometries @ index.js:41578
loadMesh @ index.js:41604
(anonymous) @ index.js:41080
_invokeOne @ index.js:41042
getDependency @ index.js:41079
createNodeMesh @ index.js:41796
(anonymous) @ index.js:41860
_invokeOne @ index.js:41042
_loadNodeShallow @ index.js:41859
loadNode @ index.js:41819
(anonymous) @ index.js:41075
_invokeOne @ index.js:41042
getDependency @ index.js:41074
loadNode @ index.js:41823
(anonymous) @ index.js:41075
_invokeOne @ index.js:41042
getDependency @ index.js:41074
loadScene @ index.js:41939
getDependency @ index.js:41071
(anonymous) @ index.js:41139
getDependencies @ index.js:41138
(anonymous) @ index.js:40954
Promise.then (async)
parse @ index.js:40952
parse @ index.js:39831
(anonymous) @ index.js:39722
(anonymous) @ index.js:24934
Promise.then (async)
load @ index.js:24927
load @ index.js:39720
Avatar @ index.js:42471
Ke @ index.js:32492
Sh @ index.js:35555
Rh @ index.js:35223
Qh @ index.js:35216
Gh @ index.js:35199
Eh @ index.js:34833
J @ index.js:30893
R @ index.js:30923
Show 43 more frames
Show less
2index.js:42287 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Access to the script at 'blob:https://www.website.com/bba676dc-3fea-4b55-badb-51addf2963a3' is denied by the document's Content Security Policy.
    at chrome-extension://nlphfnalpjgilnheibacdlongcbapgdi/assets/js/index.js:42287:25
```

I understand the security reason - but I am building a chrome extension which I want to run on my own computer; so I should be allowed to decide what I want to run on the browser cliendside right?

How can I fix this problem - no I am not the admin of the website.

**Edit: I found out there is this chrome extension that surpasses al CSP directives: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden => This means it is 100% possible to achieve what I want (without having access to the backend). How is this made?**

Comment: A solution/workaround is possible depending on what those libraries do and how you use them.

Answer (score 0):

Much as are you are indeed the ultimate authority over what can run in your Web browser, what *technically* controls what can "run" there is either the [`Content-Security-Policy`](http://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#csp-header) HTTP header value as served with the HTML document (HTTP response) in question, *or* the equivalent specified in the document with a `meta` tag, e.g. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; img-src https://*; child-src 'none';" />` ([an example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)), whichever is the *more restrictive* if both are specified.

Look for either the header served by whatever Web server that serves the HTML document or the `meta` element in the latter, read on how CSP works, amend the value of the header/element, and you will have found and fixed the issue.

To answer your question in full, the user agent gives you a *very* descriptive error message, if I may say so myself:

> Refused to create a worker from 'blob:' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "child-src 'self' *.website.com cdn.cookielaw.org geolocation.onetrust.com privacyportal-de.onetrust.com *.youtube.com pay.sandbox.datatrans.com pay.datatrans.com siteintercept.qualtrics.com *.siteintercept.qualtrics.com website.com.qualtrics.com". Note that 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'child-src' is used as a fallback.

The policy that prevents your extension from loading the worker script, *is quoted* in the message! By the value it explicitly prevents your extension from loading scripts (including those written to run workers) from blobs (`blob:` URI scheme).

You can see from the quoted value that loading from `blob:` is not allowed -- because it is not specified explicitly. To relax your policy, you will need to specify so explicitly, adding `blob:` to the list of values for `child-src` as per the [spec.](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#directive-child-src):

```
child-src 'self' *.website.com cdn.cookielaw.org geolocation.onetrust.com privacyportal-de.onetrust.com *.youtube.com pay.sandbox.datatrans.com pay.datatrans.com siteintercept.qualtrics.com *.siteintercept.qualtrics.com website.com.qualtrics.com blob:
```

The above is the value of `Content-Security-Policy` header or that of the `content` attribute of the `meta` element, it isn't clear from your question where the quoted policy is specified in your case.

You can also use `worker-src` instead of `child-src` if you only want to allow workers to load from `blob:`-URIs but not whatever else uses `child-src` part in the policy value:

```
child-src 'self' *.website.com cdn.cookielaw.org geolocation.onetrust.com privacyportal-de.onetrust.com *.youtube.com pay.sandbox.datatrans.com pay.datatrans.com siteintercept.qualtrics.com *.siteintercept.qualtrics.com website.com.qualtrics.com; worker-src blob:
```

And remember -- it doesn't matter that it's an extension of your own making, running locally even (for which the `meta` element may have specified a restrictive policy), or a "random" Web page served from an arbitrary origin on the Internet -- Content Security Policy (CSP) specification is adhered to by the [compliant] Web browser regardless, if specified. That is the entire purpose of it.

Comment: I did indeed. Good point.    ```<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="worker-src 'self' blob: *.website.com cdn.cookielaw.org geolocation.onetrust.com privacyportal-de.onetrust.com *.youtube.com pay.sandbox.datatrans.com pay.datatrans.com siteintercept.qualtrics.com *.siteintercept.qualtrics.com website.com.qualtrics.com" />```
Didn't work.

Comment: I tried to make the html page accept requests from the chrome extension itself like this (with npm Helmet):
  ```const cspContent = `worker-src 'self' ${chrome.runtime.getURL("assets/*")}`;``` and then injected the meta into the head like this: ```<Helmet><meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content={cspContent} /></Helmet>``` => Does not work at all. IT MUST BE POSSIBLE!!

Comment: I know next to nothing about React, unfortunately. I hope someone familiar with React specifically is able to help you here and explain how to have React apply the policy. React is a framework -- it aims to work with "batteries included" and as such will offer its own mechanisms for specifying CSP, given how it may run on a number of different Web servers, including its own (through Node.js, I imagine).

Comment: See also https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#meta-element which warns that the CSP specified with a `meta` element only applies to content that _follows_ it. But more importantly when CSP is specified with both the HTTP header on the response _and_ a `meta` element, the _more restrictive_ policy value will apply, so you _cannot_ "relax" the policy in `meta` if the value in the HTTP header is more restrictive, and vice versa!

Comment: I knew it is somehow possible; look at this chrome extension: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden this makes it possible for me to load my scripts, and run workers on the website. NOW the question: HOW do they do that?

Comment: @Suisse, Web Extensions is an API and it allows an extension to rewrite HTTP requests and responses (when the user allows corresponding permissions, of course), so it's absolutely trivial for an extension to strip a `Content-Security-Policy` header for some or all responses it governs. This doesn't mean the Web has become insecure suddenly -- one needs to install the extension for it to have the effect, obviously. And your application still won't work for anyone else. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest

Comment: hehe @Armen Michaeli thx GPT xD haha I got exactly the same response lol :D but thx it helped me. The core information is: with chrome extensions you can access the HTTP request API of the browser and manipulate the response before it renders.

Comment: it doesn't work anymore -.- not even with the disable-content-security chrome extension..